# Can a PC react to phone headset controls?

Tags: audio, remote, sound-card, microphone, headset

I have seen MacBook users plug in their headsets and being able to use the remote controls for volume, play and pause without a problem. According to [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/38492/46651), the signals are sent over the wire for the mic signal, so even when using an adapter to regular 3-pol Microphone and Stereo jacks, this should work, provided the soundcard is designed to interpret those signals.

Are there soundcards that actually do this, or would it be possible to write a driver that added that capability to a soundcard? Is there a name for this feature?